# How to determine sum of an alternating power series and to prove that sum is positive

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

I am working on a problem involving an alternating power series as follows:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{a-2} (-1)^{a+b-i-2}(a+b-i-1)x^{a+b-i-2}$$

$a$ and $b$ is constant with $0<x<1$

I would like to determine an expression which is used to calculate the sum of this series and to prove the expression is positive. However, I have no idea how to start. Does anyone have any hints or ideas about this problem? Please let me know. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Integrate the expression respect to $x$ and see what happen.

Comment: Notice that your sum is actually the derivative of a finite geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Some transformations to make the expression easier manageable.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=0}^{a-2}&(-1)^{a+b-i-2}(a+b-i-1)x^{a+b-i-2}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{a-2}(b+1+i)(-x)^{b+i}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{i=b+1}^{a+b-1}i(-x)^{i-1}\tag{2}\\
> &=-D_x\sum_{i=b+1}^{a+b-1}(-x)^i\tag{3}\\
> &=D_x\left(\frac{(-x)^{a+b}-(-x)^{b+1}}{1+x}\right)\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we revert the summation order by transforming the index $i \rightarrow a-2-i$
- In (2) we shift the index $i \rightarrow i+b+1$
- In (3) we apply the differential operator $D_x:=\frac{d}{dx}$
- In (4) we use the generalised formula for the *[finite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Generalized_formula)*